# In React I want to use component, that I locally built (CKeditor 5)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ckeditor

I am working on React app, just React. No Angular etc.

I wanted to use CKeditor 5. Their documentation is pretty good as far as React apps go (managed to use their prebuild included editor), but they don't really mention how to use custom built component for React, just in general. They only add example for html which I do understand.

So I tried quite hard to use this.

I've used this webpage https://ckeditor.com/ckeditor-5/online-builder/ to generate editor with my preferences. Downloaded the zip file with build and the code.

Directly import from build folder into crashed as it was too large. So I tried different approaches.

Last one, that looks like it should work, was to install it as a module using npm. So I installed it and it went just fine. Its in node modules as `"ckeditor5-custom-build"`, in package.json (`"ckeditor5-custom-build": "file:src/components/ckeditor5"`) webpage loads just fine but when i try to import it in any way it doesn't recognize it as a module.

`import CKEditor from 'ckeditor5-custom-build';`
also tried
`import {ClassicEditor} from 'ckeditor5-custom-build';` which makes more sense.

All I get is Module not found:

> Can't resolve 'ckeditor5-custom-build'

in. How can I use this?

I also tried just directly using it (add this gist below to my code), installing all of the dependencies but problem is, the dependencies won't match my project and it crashes.Still I think the first approach I tried should somehow work, I have no idea how though.

Here is the code of generated component so you can imagine what featured did I use.
https://gist.github.com/ladislavbili/68e1c6126ae6daa781fed1469352c12e

Thank you for help in advance

Comment: look at ur package.json whether it's installed, if u can't find it in there>> npm install --save ckeditor << and follow the documentations.